# Flyway setting placeholders programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I have a very simple Spring Boot application which uses Flyway for database migrations. I want to set Flyway placeholders programmatically using Spring configuration class before migration starts.

What I do is:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private Flyway flyway;

  @Value("${threedsserver.db.tableSpaces.data:pg_default}")
  private String tablespaceData;

  @Value("${threedsserver.db.tableSpaces.index:pg_default}")
  private String tablespaceIndex;

  @Value("${threedsserver.db.tableSpaces.lob:pg_default}")
  private String tablespaceLob;

  @PostConstruct
  void setFlywayPlaceholders() {
    Map<String, String> placeholders = flyway.getPlaceholders();
    placeholders.put("tablespace_data", tablespaceData);
    placeholders.put("tablespace_index", tablespaceIndex);
    placeholders.put("tablespace_lob", tablespaceLob);
    flyway.setPlaceholders(placeholders);
  }
}
```

Then in my migration script I use `${tablespace_data}` property. The migration fails with :

```
No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${tablespace_data}
```

I suppose the migration starts before the configuration file is processed. 
How to fix this? I don't want to use application.properties for setting flyway placeholders, but all other properties like `spring.flyway.user`, `spring.flyway.password`, etc want to be set by the application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FlywayConfigurationCustomizer` like this :

```
import org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayConfigurationCustomizer
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
class CustomFlywayConfiguration : FlywayConfigurationCustomizer {
    override fun customize(configuration: FluentConfiguration?) {
        configuration?.placeholders?.put("tablespace_index", "some_value")
    }
}
```

I have samples for spring boot flyway integration [here](https://github.com/vinodhinic/spring-boot-flyway/tree-save/master/README.md)